# want to sort default MUI data grid but only work in one field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

so basically i want set some sort default for field in data MUI datagrid it work but only work for one field

```
const initialSortModel = Role === 'owner'
    ? [
        {
            field: 'status',
            sort: 'asc',
        },
        {
            field: 'post_time',
            sort: 'desc',
        }
    ]
    : Role === 'admin'
    ? [
            {
                field: 'full_name',
                sort: 'desc',
            }
    ]
    : [
        {
            field: 'default_field',
            sort: 'asc',
        }
    ];

    const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState(initialSortModel);
```

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            let url = adminapi.getListPosting + `?page=${page + 1}&size=${pageSize}&search=${searchText}&sort=${sortModel[0].field} ${sortModel[0].sort}`
            if (filterModel) {
                url += `&query=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filterModel.items))}`
            }
            const response = await axios.get(url, configDefaultHeadersWithToken(token))
            const data = await response.data.result.data
            setRowCount(data[0])
            setData(data[1])
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
```

```
 sortingMode="server"
 onSortModelChange={(newSortModel) => setSortModel(newSortModel as any)}
```

Data grid itself already server side cause went datagrid still in client side this sort model work, is there something need to be set in backend ?

how to make the sort model itself work for mutiple field in datagrid ?

Comment: Note that multi-sorting is only enabled on the Pro version of MUI. Could that be your issue?

Comment: this the one that don't really understand what consider multi-sorting is, is it when you click mutiple field header to sort or just any kind sorting more than one field